# SQL 2005 Reporting Services custom report item (CRI) - what are the limits?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345265.aspx) (and other sources) about custom report items (CRI) for reporting services 2005. It looks like I'm limited to generating a bitmap. Not even with some mapping overlay for detecting mouse clicks on it. Is there away to go around this? There are two things I would like to do:

- Embed HTML directly into the report, to format dynamic text.
- Embed flash (swf) control in the report. This could be done with HTML if the previous point is possible. But maybe there is another way

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't missing anything.

For me, like you mentioned, the main disadvantage is, that with a CRI you can only render images. You don't get any scalable text or something similar.
If you want include swf, you need to render it as static image.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the report as HTML and include the report using a floating frame in a page with the swf file. You can use functions to format dynamic text. SSRS 2008 solves some of these problems with the "richly" formated textbox (not RTF). it may worth a look, if it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Data Dynamics Reports](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDRPT/Default.aspx)  which has all of the RS features and has better support for custom report items with a complete API not just bitmaps.