# Creating a custom SSRS control

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, controls, service

Is it possible to create a custom third party for Reporting Services?

The Dundas chart controls are an example of this however I am unsure if support for these have been internally built into SSRS..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

After consulting google I've found that SSRS has CRIs (Custom Report Items). These can be created in a .NET language by implementing the ICustomReportItem interface (for the rendering) and inheriting from the CustomReportItemDesigner class (for the designer). These use the Microsoft.ReportDesigner and Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces namespaces.

There is also a restriction in CRIs that the end output needs to be an image. This would make any interactivity very difficult.

For more information see

[Jazz Up Your Data Using Custom Report Items In SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188686.aspx)

[Creating a Custom Report Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345224.aspx)

Comment: I am currently unsure if there are any restrictions/issues in regards to what is rendered. I'm curious to see how well it all works when exporting to html, pdf, etc.

Comment: Restrictions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821/sql-2005-reporting-services-custom-report-item-cri-what-are-the-limits

Answer (score 1):

The Dundas controls have some internal knowledge of SSRS (although they are build with the public API). For example they workaround certain SSRS CRI limitations using reflection - I found that by default in SSRS 2008 CRI can have only one drill trough action - something that Dundas and other vendors (Nevron) by the way workaround...

Otherwise interactivity will be limited to Tooltip, URL link, Bookmark and Jump to Report actions for all custom reports and the image output is only raster.